# How to add a user defined value to the select list of values from dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny R, and as part of a project I would have to show distinct values for selection in a selectlist, but I also need to provide an option called "All" to query with.

```
dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE)
fluidPage(
  title = "ABC XYZ",
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel("ABC XYZ"),
    sidebarPanel(
selectInput("region", label = "Region", 
          choices = unique(dataset$region), 
          selected = 1)
 )
)
```

Can anyone help me achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create an additional `level` or `unique` element 'All' in `choices` and update with `updateSelectInput`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#using a reproducible example
dataset <- iris
allchoice <- c("All", levels(dataset$Species))
```

-ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "ABC XYZ",
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel("ABC XYZ"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", label = "Species", 
                  choices = allchoice, multiple = TRUE),
                 verbatimTextOutput("selected")
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput('out')))
  )
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if("All" %in% input$species) {
      selected <- setdiff(allchoice, "All")
      updateSelectInput(session, "species", selected = selected)       

         }
    })

output$selected <- renderText({
  paste(input$species, collapse = ", ")

})

output$out <- renderDataTable({
     dataset %>%
            filter(Species %in% input$species)      

})
```

-run app

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]