# Using observer to hold the resulted data subset in a vector

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny R.
Can anyone help me solve the issue below.

I am trying to plot the data using a dataset, and with a user defined option "All" added to the "selectlist" of "region" provided in UI.

When "All" option is selected from "selectlist", how can I use the below observer to store information about all the regions into vector "l", so that the same can be used to query based on other user inputs

```
observe({
    if("All" %in% input$region) {
      selected <- setdiff(allchoice, "All")
      updateSelectInput(session, "region", selected = selected)       

         }
    })
```

Ref: [How to add a user defined value to the select list of values from dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160382/how-to-add-a-user-defined-value-to-the-select-list-of-values-from-dataset/46160887#46160887)

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library("RMySQL")
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE)
dataset$X <- NULL
allchoice <- c("All", levels(dataset$region))

fluidPage(
  title = "ABC XYZ",
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel("ABC XYZ"),
    sidebarPanel(      
      dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                       label = 'Date Input',
                       start = as.Date("1967-01-01"), end = Sys.Date()),

      selectInput("region", label = "Region", 
                  choices = allchoice, 
                  selected = 1),

      selectInput("gender", label = "Gender", 
                  choices = unique(dataset$gender), multiple = TRUE, 
                  selected = unique(dataset$gender)),

      selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
      selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[8]]),
    hr()
    ),
     mainPanel(
      column(12, plotlyOutput("plot1")),
      hr(),
     column(12, plotlyOutput("plot2"))
    )
  )
)
```

**Server.r**

```
library(ggplot2)
library("RMySQL")
library("mgcv")
library(plotly)
function(input, output, session) {
    dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE)
    dataset$X <- NULL

    dataset$date <- as.Date(dataset$date)

    if(input$region == "All"){
      l <- observe({
      if("All" %in% input$region) {
        selected <- setdiff(allchoice, "All")
        updateSelectInput(session, "region", selected = selected)       
       }
     })
    }
    else{
      l <- reactive(subset(dataset, region %in% input$region))
    }
    k <- reactive({subset(l(), date >= as.Date(input$dateRange[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$dateRange[2]))})
    n <- reactive(subset(k(), gender %in% input$gender))

    #output plots
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(n(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point(alpha=0.4)
    ggplotly(p)
    })

    output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    q <- ggplot(n(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_smooth()
    ggplotly(q)
    })
}
```

**Error I am facing -**

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    46: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    45: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    44: $.reactivevalues
    43: $ [D:\Demo\server.R#36]
    42: server $ [D:\Demo\server.R#36]
     1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Note: My vocabulary above may be off, so please correct me if I'm wrong, I am totally new to the world of R.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5128
    We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
    Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
    Warning in origRenderFunc() :
    Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "2988253b22c1"; Shiny doesn't use them
    We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
    Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
    `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam'
    Warning in origRenderFunc() : Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "29885be33e8"; Shiny doesn't use them
```

and even when i do that, I am getting many exceptions and sometimes the same exceptions as above again. Just worried if the same will affect the application in the long run, can you suggest anything about that?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have not provided an example data** so i can only guess and via looking at your error which says clearly whats the problem: no active reactive context, i assume that it is exactly in this part:

```
if(input$region == "All"){
      l <- observe({
      if("All" %in% input$region) {
        selected <- setdiff(allchoice, "All")
        updateSelectInput(session, "region", selected = selected)       
       }
     })
    }
    else{
      l <- reactive(subset(dataset, region %in% input$region))
    }
```

**[!]** but actually i do not understand what for you need the `observer`...i think it should work totally fine if you just use `if...else...` statement.

**[!]** And additionally i have no idea why at first you say you wanna get the vector of choices (except `"All"`) and you use it as selected choice in `selectInput`, may i ask what for?
and `else` statement should give you subset of the data based on `input$region`.

So shortly saying: `if` gives you `updatedSelectInput` and `else` gives you dataset --> It actually does not make sense at all..

and should be as simple as that, if `"All"` is selected then there is no need to subset the `dataset`, if any other choice then `"All"` is selected then the subset of the `dataset` should happen:

```
l <- reactive({
if(input$region == "All"){
dataset
}else{
dataset <- subset(dataset, region %in% input$region)
}})
```

Comment: I did get to plot the information with the way you suggested, but that way I am getting exceptions to use the dev version of ggplot2 from hadley - github.
Please check my EDIT 1 for the exception details.

Comment: could you provide sample data so i can run your code?